# jGrowl in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, jgrowl

I have to search a particular member and so as i write the member id in the textbox and click the search button, I want the message to be displayed "member not found"(if not found) in jgrowl otherwise it will be redirected to the memberId page.

Now the problem is when the button is clicked i write the details in button_click(c#) event about conn estd, redirect to member page if found etc. But what if not found? i.e how to provoke the JGrowl(which is in a javascript in asp.net)? how to call that?

I am confused regarding the wayI have to implement it.
Would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanking You
Indranil

P.S. After implementing the snippet

```
string js = "$.jGrowl('Hello world!');";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "jgrowlwarn", js, true);
```

from Mr Gabriel the jGrowl works fine but it looks like this ->
http://www.4shared.com/photo/vx7mKAnL/jGRowl.html
any suggestions?
FYI I've other jquery functions in the project.

Comment: Seeing as how the color of the box is very similar to that of your left navigation, it is very possibly a CSS problem.

Comment: could u suggest any possible way to fix it?

Comment: Indeed it was a CSS problem...Thanks a lot..
PROBLEM SOLVED

Comment: one last question- How to mark this thread as solved?

Comment: Indranil, you have to Click the Green Checked sign next to the answer that answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this when the check failed to find the user:
it depends if you are using AJAX (ScriptManager or not)
if not:

```
string js = "$.jGrowl('Hello world!');";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "jgrowlwarn", js, true);
```

if so:

```
string js = "$.jGrowl('Hello world!');";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(pageBase), "jgrowlwarn", js, true);
```

Comment: AJAX Scriptmanager Iam just using for displaying a calender(textbox).
Just to make sure- this code has to be written in C# right?

Comment: Bravo!! the first snippet works great...thanks a lot.
Now there is another problem i am facing. The jGrowl has some blue block in it(there might be some conflict with the jquery, m using jquery too). si there any way to get the default(smoke) jGrowl?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with jGrowl, can you explain what do you mean by blue block?

Comment: i gave a link...do check the image here->
http://www.4shared.com/photo/vx7mKAnL/jGRowl.html

Comment: it was a CSS problem...Thanks a lot for being there..
PROBLEM SOLVED